# Laravel 5 Caching Query

Tags: php, performance, laravel, caching, laravel-5

Does anyone knows where Laravel 5 store query cache?

I have cached query with:

```
> $data["test"] = \Cache::remember("delivery_report", 1, function()
> {
>     return DeliveryReport::where("test", "<>", "N/A")->groupBy("test")->get();
> });
```

I just want to know what technique Laravel use for caching. Text files or ... ?

Comment: it stores on project/storage/framework/cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are multiple available storages, it depends on your cache configuration. You can see available cache storages in your **config/cache.php** file. Currently used storage is defined by setting a proper value to **default** parameter.

By default Laravel uses file storage. In the config file you can see that it's saving cached data to **storage_path().'/framework/cache'** - if you haven't reconfigured project paths, it should by default map to **storage/framework/cache**.